# Can XACML policies be defined in term of Service type?

Tags: web-services, xaml, access-control

I was just wondering if XACML policies can be defined in term of service types ? In other words, If I have a system where service types are defined with wsdl elements, for instance, (operations, binding, etc.) and service instances that are providers implementing the service types. Then:

1) Can I define access control policies in XACML in term of this service types instead of service instances ?

2) Does any XACML implementation support this ?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can definitely define XACML policies in terms of service types. Bear in mind that with XACML you can use just about any attributes about the requesting user, the targeted resource (be it a document, a web service, a database...). Anything you can write in 'plain old English', you can also express in XACML.

I would suppose that most implementations support this. [Axiomatics](http://www.axiomatics.com), where I work, definitely does.

You may also want to look at XML gateways since they act as the perfect policy enforcement point (PEP) for web services. Check out Layer 7 for instance. They integrate with Axiomatics.

Cheers,
David.

Comment: Do you happen to know any opensource XML gateway ?

Comment: I googled around and found this - http://www.corisecio.com/products/soa/xml_gateway/overview.php